# Phrasal-verb word order

Tags: word-order

[Cambridge Dictionary says that we must only put the particles of phrasal verbs after the object if the object is a personal pronoun.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs) Now, I really would like you to prove my thought about it, viz.: sentence 2 is totally wrong, whereas 1, 3, and 4 are correct, right?

1. I've been trying to figure myself out recently;
2. I've been trying to figure out myself recently;
3. I have finally figured out everything;
4. I have finally figured everything out.

Comment: What makes you think 2. is wrong?

Comment: To my reading 3 is wronger than 2, but none are so wrong as to be unintelligible.

Comment: The participles of phrasal verbs? What does that mean?

Comment: With a [phrasal verb](https://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/various-grammar-rules/phrasal-verbs-structure-and-examples) (verb + adverb), the position of the object (a noun) is flexible, i.e. it can sit either between the verb and the adverb or after the adverb: She took her coat off. (The object her coat is between the verb and the adverb.) She took off her coat.

Comment: ...but it seems ***myself*** isn't the same kind of pronoun as, say, ***it***. So OP's examples #1 and #2 are both fine, as is *I've been trying to figure **it** out recently*. But we *can't* say *I've been trying to figure out **it** recently*.

Comment: @Fumblefingers  Yes.  But what about when pronouns appear?  For example, "as soon as she heard the whistling of the kettle, she turned  and took it off."  You cannot say "... took off it.", and you certainly cannot say ".... took off it from the hob", though you can get away with saying "...took off the kettle from the hob.  Possibly, this is just one of those cases of inconsistent evolution.

Comment: @Tuffy: But ***taking a kettle off** / away (from the heat)* isn't a phrasal verb. On the other hand *The office joker **took off** the boss* looks like a phrasal verb to me. And I think the boss could reasonably say *I don't like it when he **takes me off*** OR *...when he **takes off me***, so whatever I thought about the position of pronouns with phrasal verbs is probably wrong.

Comment: ....but you can certainly *turn on the light* or *turn on the light*. And *turn it on* is fine, but *turn on it* doesn't work at all for that sense (to *turn on it* could only mean *to **attack** it*)..

Comment: Quite right.  I didn't think carefully enough.

Comment: Dictionaries are not the right place to look for grammar. Dictionaries don't do grammar; dictionaries do lexicon. Grammars do grammar. There are transitive and intransitive phrasal verbs in English; I use the term only for those subject to Particle Shift with personal pronoun direct objects. _Take off_ is one; _take it off_ but not *_take off it_.  Are you asking about whether reflexive DO must appear between verb and particle? Construct examples and see.

Comment: [It looked like I was trying to **figure out myself**, but they were trying to help me **figure myself out.**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22like+I+was+trying+to+figure+out+myself%22) Not sure it would make any difference if the two sequences in that sentence were swapped.

Comment: I think that you mean "particles" instead of "participles". It would be clearer if you cited your source. ("Cambridge Dictionary" is pretty vague.)

Comment: You don’t have any personal pronouns in your examples. You have a reflexive pronoun and an indefinite pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

I have no source for the following assertions other than my own ear as a native speaker of American English. All four sound ok. There's less semantic tangle in 1 and 2 if "recently" is moved to the beginning of the sentence, or as the second word ("I've recently"), just as was done with 3 and 4. One oddity of 2 is that in flight, the listener might give it the same value as "I myself have been trying to figure out..." -- in this case, the listener expects to hear what the speaker is trying to figure out. But after a good pause at the full stop, the listener will probably realize that what is meant was something like "I'm having strange thoughts and feelings, I'm acting strangely, and I don't understand it."

Answer (score 0):

*Myself* is a reflexive or emphatic pronoun, not a personal pronoun.

Note also that *my*, *your*, *our*, etc., are possessive adjectives, not pronouns, and *mine*, *yours*, *ours*, etc., are possessive pronouns, not personal pronouns.